# NSString testing won't evaluate to true when it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate

So, I've been trying to get an NSPredicate to work, and it should. But it won't.
I've decided to loop through this array to test how come, and I've gotten to this point with testing

```
- (void)getItemsForGroup:(NSString *)groupID completion:(MenuQueryBlock)completion{

 ...

    for (NSDictionary *group in [[[[[[self.singleMenuSet objectForKey:@"menuList"] firstObject] objectForKey:@"UnitMenu"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"groups"] objectForKey:@"group"]) {
        NSLog(@"test");
        NSLog(@"Group MasterGID: %@",[group objectForKey:@"MasterGID"]);
        NSLog(@"test_ MasterGID: %@",groupID);

        if ([[group objectForKey:@"MasterGID"] isEqualToString:groupID]) {
            NSLog(@"Selected Group: %@",group);
        }
    }
....
completion(....)
}
```

Here is the section of the log where "Selected Group" should print.

```
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] test_ MasterGID: 24000040
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] test
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] Group MasterGID: 24000039
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] test_ MasterGID: 24000040
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] test
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] Group MasterGID: 24000040
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] test_ MasterGID: 24000040   <----right after this line
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.738 business_sect[3687:144610] test
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] Group MasterGID: 24000041     
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] test_ MasterGID: 24000040
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] test
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] Group MasterGID: 24000042
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] test_ MasterGID: 24000040
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] test
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] Group MasterGID: 24000043
 2015-09-02 11:42:24.739 business_sect[3687:144610] test_ MasterGID: 24000040
```

So why isn't the "Selected Group" printing?

Comment: `[group objectForKey:@"MasterGID"]` is really a `NSString` or is it a `NSNumber`?

Comment: try using if ([[group objectForKey:@"MasterGIP"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) and figure out if this is actually a number or a string

Comment: Could there be a invisible character somewhere? `hasPrefix:`//`hasSuffix:` may help point it out (I'm thinking of an invisible character at beginning or at the end). Maybe converting them to `NSData` and check if they are identical.

Comment: Turns out the problem is that the passed groupID was interpreted as NSNumber

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
    if ([(NSString *)group[@"MasterGID"] hash] == groupID.hash) {
        NSLog(@"Selected Group: %@",group);
    }
```